# Can anybody explain the request-response cycle in a struts application?

Tags: java, jsp, request, response, struts-1

I am developing a struts based application but i regularly get stucked with the requests or variables unable to be resolved.

I think this is because i still don't understand the request and response cycle of the Struts application.

Can anybody help me out ??

Answer (score 5):

awesome explanation here please go throught this link
http://rollerjm.free.fr/pro/Struts11.html#2

Basically struts app will run on three components

a) ActionServlet
b) struts-config.xml
c) Controler

When an user request for an request by having url as *.do , Actionservlet will lookup of that .do configuration in struts-config.xml, you can see those in "form-beans" and "action-mapping" tags

First when user request for request as "http/:....../user.do" this "user" you can also see in that "action-mapping" tag, under this "action" tag with attribute "path" .

So ActionServlet will look for this attribute when ever an request is requested.
After that it will check the name attribute "name=userform". At this stage, it will look for with this name is there any form-bean containing same name attribute as "name=userform".

So you can find action tag name attribute and formbean tag name attributes are same.

after it identifies, it will create the form object by send it to Requestprocessor and roots the request to particaular action class.

Comment: Thanks Damodar. The link is very usefull.

Comment: only useful . is it is not votable?

Comment: I don't think so. The class diagrams can be very confusing for any novice programmer. Don't you think so ?

Comment: do you have knowledge on struts?

Comment: As i said i am using it. So i have a basic working knowledge of struts.

Comment: +1 I think i will ask Santa for a diagram like this for Struts2. It's fantastic!

Comment: just replay me if you are following

Comment: please let me know after you gone through the above, i have to provide finishing touch.

Comment: @Lokesh Sah, please be patient to read the UML diagrams, which are dissected the workflow so clearly and thoroughly.

Comment: I have a doubt : What if i have some data in the View (say jsp page) and i wan't to send this data to a action class. And yes the data on the view is not in a form. Also i don't want to store it in a session object.

Comment: have it in a valueobject and declare that valueobject in form